# CTE + INSERT INTO Error: String or binary data will be truncated

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

```
; 
With CTE AS 
( 
       SELECT  IIF (ISNULL (POLHOLDERID,'') ='', Member_id, PolHolderId) AS RespMemberId, 
        CASE WHEN (  Member_id = PolHolderId)  then 1 When ISNULL (PolHolderId,'') <> '' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END AS RespLevel ,  
       ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY [Case Base#] ORDER BY CASE WHEN (  Member_id = PolHolderId)  then 1 When ISNULL (PolHolderId,'') <> '' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, DOB) AS RN, 
       * FROM [dbo].[AllHRS]
       )
INSERT INTO dbo.Eligibility (
      [CaseBaseNo]
      ,[RecordType]
      ,[HealthPlanId]
      ,[PlanId]
      ,[HPMemberId]
      ,[HPMemberId2]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[MiddleName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Street1]
      ,[Street2]
      ,[City]
      ,[State]
      ,[Zip]
      ,[GroupNumber]
      ,[UserDefined1]
      ,[UserDefined2]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[TerminationDate]
      ,[InitialActivationCode]
      ,[LoadAmount]
      ,[ServiceDate]
      ,[ServiceCode]
      ,[ServiceDescription]
      ,[HPReferenceNo]
      ,[IssueNewCard]
      ,[Language]
      ,[Filler])
SELECT 
[Case Base#] as CaseBase, 
'117A' as RecordType, 
'H81' as HealthPlanID, 
'H81-117A' as PlanId, 
RespMemberId AS MemberId,
null, 
IIF (ISNULL (POLHOLDERID,'') ='', Member_First_Name, IIF(Charindex(',', PolHolderName)> 0, Substring(PolHolderName, 1,Charindex(',', PolHolderName)-1), PolHolderName)), 
NULL,
IIF (ISNULL (POLHOLDERID,'') ='', Member_Last_Name, Substring(LTRIM(IIF(Charindex(',', PolHolderName)> 0, Substring(PolHolderName, Charindex(',', PolHolderName)+1,LEN(PolHolderName)), PolHolderName)),1,charIndex(' ',
     LTRIM(IIF(Charindex(',', PolHolderName)> 0, Substring(PolHolderName, Charindex(',', PolHolderName)+1,LEN(PolHolderName)), PolHolderName))+' '))),
ADDRESS1, 
ADDRESS2, 
CITY, 
STATE, 
ZIP, 
[Case Base#], 
NULL, 
NULL, 
FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS [START DATE], 
IIF([Member TermDate] is null, '', 
DATEADD(month,30,[Member TermDate])), 
NULL, 
0.00, 
[INTERVIEW DATE], 
CASE
    WHEN Clinical_Variable not like '%57' and Clinical_Variable not like '%58' THEN 'HRS'
    WHEN Clinical_Variable like '%57' THEN 'HRA'
    WHEN Clinical_Variable like '%58' THEN 'CC'
END as Service_Code, 
NULL, 
0.00, 
'YES', 
NULL, 
NULL
FROM CTE WHERE RN =1
```

Little background. We get a file from our reporting department. It is IT's job to do a bunch of aggregations and shove it into another file, an eligibility file.

The error says:

`Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 2
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

Can someone help? Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to stuff 10 pounds of shinola into a 5 pound bag.

Comment: excellent observation. Sounds technical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error its evident that for one of the columns(or more) the data you are trying to set is bigger than the column size.. I would look at the name columns and the address columns. An easy way to debug this would be to put a MAX(LEN()) around the columns in your select clause and compare it with your table definition.

Comment: True, I commented out sections of the code until I saw where it was failing. The error made me think the data in memory was going to be truncated therefore not allowing me to insert..but i guess it makes sense being that it wasn't until I tried to insert and match up the lengths of the fields that I had the issue. Thanks man.